# Convert negative angle to positive: Involves invalid operand use

Tags: c++, c, math

I am attempting to convert a negative angle (in degrees) to positive. But I am getting a compile error saying:

> test.cpp invalid operands of types 'double' and 'int' to binary 'operator%'
>   test.cpp invalid operands of types 'float' and 'int' to binary 'operator%'

My code:

```
double to_positive_angle(double angle)
{
   return ((3600000 + angle) % 360);
}

float to_positive_angle(float angle)
{
   return ((3600000 + angle) % 360);
}
```

Its obviously because I am trying to use the Modulus operator on a Float and Double.

Are the any ways I can successfully convert a negative angle (float) to a positive one (float)? Or ways that I can overcome the modulus compile error?

Comment: Your angle is in degrees, correct?

Comment: why are you adding `3600000` to the angle?

Comment: He is adding 3600000 because that is a multiple of 360, one rotation, and it will turn most negative angles (>= -3600000) into a positive equivalent angle.

Comment: This is extremely pedantic point but all of the standard libraries dealing with angles use radius not degrees, so I would try to make any code I write use radians as well. I would convert too and from degrees when outputting and inputing only.

Comment: @NathanDay: There are actually lots of reasons to prefer working in degrees. In radians, there is no `x` such that `cos(x)==0` or `sin(x)==1`, etc. This also means successive rounds around the circle will not give you identical values for `sin` and `cos`. With degrees, all of those problems go away. Moreover, degrees are better than the other natural option, `sinpi(x)` defined as `sin(pi*x)`, because even in that form it's impossible to represent 30 and 60 degree angles exactly (and thus there's no `x` with `sin(x)==0.5`, etc.).

Comment: @R.. I see your point, but I would take the position that floats are just engineering approximations and anytime you display them you are going to have to do some kind of round. If I was to use degrees to get the features you are putting forward then I would use integers instead. Integers are for exact values, float are for approximations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay perhaps I'm a little slow, but I'm not sure why you're using a 3600000.0 constant.

If you're just trying to convert a negative angle to it's positive value, you can just add 360.0 until you get a positive number.

```
double to_positive_angle(double angle)
{
   angle = fmod(angle, 360);
   while(angle < 0) { //pretty sure this comparison is valid for doubles and floats
     angle += 360.0;
   }

   return angle;
}
```

Comment: This is going to be terribly slow if `angle` is large, and might **never** terminate since `angle+360==angle` is possible for large `angle`.

Comment: @R.. Great point. I didn't even consider large values of angle.

Comment: Of course, the loop can be made faster yet stay general by adding 3600000 each time through, instead of 360.  Why not?

Comment: Adding 3600000 will destroy the precision, especially in the float version.

Comment: I cannot vote this up, as it uses a loop when a single-step operation will suffice

Answer (score 14):

This version works for all possible inputs, not just ones greater than 3600000, and solves the `%` issue you were experiencing.

```
double to_positive_angle(double angle)
{
   angle = fmod(angle, 360);
   if (angle < 0) angle += 360;
   return angle;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't use the modulo operator on floating-point types.  You should use `fmod` for this.

```
return fmod( 3600000.0 + angle, 360.0 );
```

Be a little wary of rounding and precision errors you might introduce with the above operation.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the smartest way:

```
void get_positve_angle(double theta)
{
    return fmod(fmod(theta,360)+360,360);
}
```